# Who are deities with Ayyappa Swamy?

Tags: identification-request, ayyappa, deity

In the below image, the two deities seen under Ayyappa.

[image]

Who are these deities? Is they are folk forms of any deities (like Ayyappa is folk form of Dharma Shasta)?

Comment: Where is the 'existing answer' you want to reward??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the left side of the steps we can see one deity and on the right side we can see two deities. These are Upadevatas (sub deities) as per the [Sabarimala website](https://sabarimala.kerala.gov.in/upadevadhas):

The deity on the left is **Valiya Kadutha Swami**

> The small shrine
> of Valiya Kadutha is located on the left side of holy steps. Valiya
> Kadutha is also an attendant of Lord Ayyappa.

and the two deities on the right are: **Karuppu Swami & Karuppai Amma**

> Karuppu Swami & Karuppai Amma: The temple of Karuppu Swami is located
> on the right side of the Pathinettam Padi or the eighteen holy steps.
> The temple of Karuppu Swami also includes the murti of Karuppai Amma.
> They both were people from forest who helped Lord Ayyappa in his
> divine mission and are believed to have divine power.

Comment: Thank you, but you didn't answer to these deities are folk forms of which deity. Can you provide that?

Comment: If they are incarnations of some known deities is something I don't know .. the Sabarimala website also have not mentioned anything on that @Boovanaes

Comment: i think Karuppu Swami is folk version of Kalaka (which means black-complexined one), a gana of Shiva. Because, name of Karuppu Swami also has similar meaning and Kalaka is also once worshipped, according to Agni Purana.

Comment: Possible .. nice find @Boovanaes